# Store value in Jquery variable and use it for all pages

Tags: jquery

I declared a variable "selected_area" and outside the function but it wont work outside... i am trying to get value by clicking and want to use it for all pages but when i go to the other page the value is not the same..

```
      var selected_area;
      $('#area').on('click', '.list-group-item', function () { 
        var btn_area = $(this);
        //selected_area = btn_area.text();
        $("#selected_area").text(selected_area);
        });
        alert(selected_area);
```

Comment: this code is work good for only one page... i want the changes for all pages

Comment: either save value in `PHP SESSION` or use `localStorage` of javascript

Comment: Depends on what other tech you are using, eg php/C#.  Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+javascript+variable+to+another+page

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the issue by using localStorage. 
Here's an example, I'll use prompt() for short.

First page

```
window.onload = function() {
   var getInput = prompt("Hey World ");
   localStorage.setItem("storageName",getInput);
}
```

Second page

```
window.onload = alert(localStorage.getItem("storageName"));
```

You can also use cookies but localStorage allows much more spaces, and they aren't sent back to servers when you request pages.